# Identify Seed from Vine

Tags: seeds

[image: Seeds from an unknown vine]

Can someone help me identify these seeds? I had them in a small packet labeled vine seeds. I either didn't know the name of the vine or assumed I'd remember it.

Thanks, Katy Bain

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking at photos, I'm sure they are the lablab seeds. However, I'm still puzzled about where or who I got them from - there's no help for me there. I will plant a few and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Lablab purpureus seeds or beans http://www.connectedseeds.org/seeds/lablab-beans. These beans/seeds are used as food in many countries, but the plant itself produces very attractive pink flowers and is often grown ornamentally in places which are warm enough or have reasonably good summers. Common name Hyacinth bean, presumably after the purple coloured pods which contain the seeds, image and info on the plant here, but the growing instructions are for the UK  https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/vegetables/lablab

Comment: Also known as Dolichos lablab. I have no idea which name is currently accepted - those darn taxonomists seem to delight in confusing us.

Comment: @Jurp - previously known as Dolichos... now reclassified as Lablab...

Answer (score 0):

It's virtually impossible to identify those, from the picture though it looks like they are partially germinated. Plant them right away, cover with about 1/4 inch soil.
You have a surprise awaiting you as to what they are, good luck.

Comment: These are not germinated - the white part is just part of the seed.